# How can I set a DNS on my router that goes nowhere

Tags: router, internet, dns

My router has three slots for DNS servers. I am using OpenDNS for the first two, but on odd occasions OpenDNS fails and I would like the third one to be something useless that essentially disables DNS/points everything to some harmless site. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not put Google's DNS server in there too?  8.8.8.8

Comment: Why would I want to do that?

Comment: @milli please read the question and think hard about what Moss is actually asking for.

Comment: I'm curious as to why OP wants this done

Comment: I have filtering in OpenDNS. If that fails then the filtering fails. I would rather have no internet than unrestricted internet at that point.

Comment: @Moses, I did read the question.  Moss implied that OpenDNS "fails", i.e., stops responding.  You just need somewhere else to resolve from, why not add a different service that's more reliable?  DNS is effectively "disabled" if OpenDNS is not responding anyway, no need to add anything to continue that behavior.  It makes no sense to add another DNS server that sends to a black hole.  Also, if this router is handing these IPs out as DNS servers via DHCP to computers, then this question makes absolutely no sense.  PCs running Windows will randomize the order they are used and cause more problems

Comment: @Moss, didn't read your other comment...   if you want real filtering you should be using something like NetNanny or something free like Dansguardian.  Just denying DNS lookups is not enough, it's not granular enough.  You need content filtering down to the URL.  (Been there, done that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you can enter `0.0.0.0` and the router will ignore the third entry and only use the other two. It depends on the router and firmware.

Alternatively you could enter a self-referring IP like `127.0.0.1` or `169.254.0.0`. Or plug in garbage IPs like `254.254.254.254`. Any IP that isn't a DNS server should work. Doing this will cause DNS lookups to time out if the first two DNS servers fail (which could qualify as your requirement of essentially disabling DNS).

You also have to make sure all the clients are getting their DNS settings from the router, otherwise they can bypass it altogether and use their own.

Comment: All this will cause is a longer timeout for DNS lookups.  Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 seems to work...eventually. Took awhile to kick in though.

Comment: @Moses, I read the question.  I just know how DNS works and was inferring the intent of the question.  There was no mention in the original question that OpenDNS was used with filtering.  Adding additional IPs for DNS resolution *that do not answer DNS queries* does nothing more than slow down DNS lookups against the OpenDNS servers.  So adding bogus IPs as DNS servers is just a dumb thing to do and doesn't help at all.  Whether you put in two IPs or three IPs doesn't matter here, they are all treated equivalently.  If one gives back "port unreachable", the others are just retried.

Comment: I am using DD-WRT, are you saying that the list of DNS servers is not prioritized? It just picks one randomly every time? I haven't been noticing any slowness, so whatever. Now are you saying that if the OpenDNS servers fail to respond it will try 127.0.0.1 which will also fail and then it will carry on to my ISP or whatever and still do a DNS lookup? Because that wasn't my experience when I forced it to use 127.0.0.1. Windows told me there was a problem with DNS and I couldn't go to any website by URL.

Comment: What I'm saying is if you give these three IPs as DNS servers via DHCP to your Windows PC, it'll just randomly change which one it's using first every 15 minutes and you get random delays on the PC (the IPs are treated as equal). If you're handing only the IP of the DD-WRT router to clients, then I don't know what the behavior is.. (I've never needed to investigate DD-WRTs DNS lookup behavior).

Comment: I'm wondering if your root problem is that you have dnsmasq enabled.  That's been a source of pain for a lot of people causing resolution timeouts because of bad cached data.  If you're not using the fancy bits of dnsmasq, try turning that off (if it's on).

Comment: @Moss This gives a little more insight on Windows' use of DNS: http://serverfault.com/a/84293

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, `127.0.0.1` should work.

Any way, have a look at the [OpenNIC Project](http://www.opennicproject.org/), which has advantages for some.